# Angular gives error when trying to handle errors that come from API calls

Tags: angular, api, error-handling

I am writing angular service class to hit APIs. When some Internal server error comes in response, I want to send error message to user. The services written for get, but giving this error.

> core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
> at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:40:1)

**sample.component.ts**

```
this.sampleService.getCurrentStatus(this.Id, fromDateToRest, 
toDateToRest).subscribe(
  (CurrentStatus: any) => {

    if (CurrentStatus && CurrentStatus.length > 0) {
       //do something
    }

    if (CurrentStatus && CurrentStatus.length == 0) {
      this.errorMessage = "No data!"
    }
    else {
      this.errorMessage = "Vehicle not found!"
    }
  },
  (error)=>{
    if (error.status == 500) {
      this.errorMessage = "Internal Server Error!"
    }
  }
);
```

**sample.service.ts**

```
getCurrentStatus(Id: String, fromDateToRest:String, toDateToRest:String): Observable<any> {

let params;
params = Object.assign( { fromDateToRest, toDateToRest } )

const httpOptions = {
  params
}

return this.restService.get<any>(URL,httpOptions);
}
```

**restService**

```
get<T>(url: string, httpOptions?: {}) {
  return this.httpClient.get<T>(url , httpOptions);
}
```

Here is the error logs

**Response**

[image]

**Console log**

[image]

I read same questions and still didn't get a solution.

Comment: Can you also paste the code of your `restService`?

Comment: The error states that you do not provide a valid stream of data to an observable. Please provide your full code, not juste a few samples where you think the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

When serve returns error response, you need to handle it in error callback method.

```
this.maintenanceService.getCurrentStatus(this.Id, fromDateToRest, toDateToRest).subscribe(
        (currentStatus) => {
            if (currentStatus && currentStatus.length > 0) {
                //do something
            } else if (currentStatus && currentStatus.length === 0) {
                this.errorMessage = "No data!"
            } else if(currentStatus && currentStatus.status === 500) {
                this.errorMessage = current status.error
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            // check error status code, if it is 500, then do some actions like you needed below
            if (error.status === 500) {
                this.errorMessage = "Internal Server Error!"
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: I tried. this didn't work for me. it didn't go error part. not print the log.

Comment: Can u pls log both response and error and attach screenshot of it

Comment: Added the both response and console log

Comment: Since error object is send as in response object, can u pls check the currentStatus object status property like below
If(currentStatus.status === 500) { this.errorMessage = current status.error}

Comment: Tried. But gives same error.

Comment: Can u check below reference might help you
https://www.querythreads.com/type-error-you-provided-an-invalid-object-where-a-stream-was-expected-you-can-provide-an-observable-promise-array-or-iterable/

Answer (score 0):

This is what You suppose to pay more attention to *You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected*

Which means exactly what it states. You did not provide any data to the service and than to the endpoint.

You have to check if in every step the data is passed correctly to another step, i.e. from component to service, from service to endpoint.

Comment: Data is passing correctly. This error comes when internal server error happen. I want to handle it & give some custom message to user

Comment: So try to update Your service to handle the response with

  map(data => {
    // Transform data 
  }),
  catchError(err => {
    // Handle errors 
  })

Answer (score 0):

try catching the error on a pipe and then return the EMPTY observable

```
import { catchError, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

this.maintenanceService.getCurrentStatus(this.Id, fromDateToRest, toDateToRest).pipe(
  catchError((e) => {
    if (e.status === 500) {
      this.errorMessage = 'Internal Server Error!';
    }

    return EMPTY
  })
).subscribe(...);
```

you are not actually treating the error:

- for Promises use for Promise.then(....).catch(e => ...);
- for async/await, encapsulate in a try-catch statement;
- for RxJs use the catchError operator.